# Detect a palm hold on touchscreen

Tags: hammer.js

I'm developing a touchscreen kiosk and need to know when the user is pressing their whole hand on the screen. The touchscreen I have seems to only have 5 touch points so need to find a solution to manage what happens when they also put their palm against the screen.
I'm using a combination or press and pan events to detect all the fingers touching, but when the palm is put onto the screen the mouseup event is fired within the pan gesture.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe I read something about detecting multiple touch points to determine this on Apple's documentation for iPads or iBooks.

Comment: Sorry, should add this is running in Chrome on OS X